# Placing a character on the border of a table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to figure out a reliable way to place a character (like an = symbol) on top of the border of a table cell.  I would end up not showing the border, but to make this clearer, I've put a screenshot of what I want to do below.

[image]

The data in the table may be different than what's shown in the picture, and therefore the table cells could be wider or skinnier.  Is there any way to somehow use the border itself as some kind of reference location for positioning a character on top of it?

I've tried adding a row above it then using `position: relative` to move the character down, but it's not reliable.  Neither is placing a different table above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the css `::before` pseudo-selector:

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
td:not(:first-child)::before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    left: -8px;
    text-align: center;
    content: "=";
}
```

You'll have to play around a little with the `witdh` and `left` properties on the `::before` content. I expected `left: -5px` to stay nicely in the middle, with `width: 10px`, but it didn't. Not sure why.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkwrjz3f/1/).

---

If you want the `=` sign to be part of the actual content you could do something like:

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text <span>=</span></td>
        <td>Some text <span>=</span></td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
table td span {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    right: -10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

(it appears too small a `width` was the culprit in previous solution for not properly aligning centered)

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57m3uczL/2/).

Comment: I had a moment and thought I'd offer a small adaptation to your `::before`-based answer (it's not sufficiently different to warrant another answer): http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jkwrjz3f/3/

Comment: @DavidThomas Not sure what all the extra properties do *exactly*, but it looks good! If you turn it into an answer, you'd have my upvote! ;-)

Comment: @DavidThomas O wait, I see now: you did away with the hardcoded equal-sign. Haha. That's a little bit much, no? ;-) I like the white background, breaking the borders, though.

Comment: Possibly, but it does look pretty... ;)

Comment: @DavidThomas It does, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is an old school method. Make the border hidden, and then add a background image of the desired glyph(s). Or add more columns with border hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to accomplish this but here's a quick [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MattSmith/1daaex2d/) I just did.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Total gal.<span class="right">=</span></th>
        <th>% of solution<span class="right">=</span></th>
        <th>Total gal. of solution</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse
}
table tr { border: 1px  solid #ccc }
table th { width: 125px }
.title { text-align: center }
.right {
    float: right;
    padding: 0
}
```